# Parsing XML file with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I would like to parse an XML file using c#. I am a beginner in that field so I need your help please.
Before I ask my question I checked on the net, and found that there is 2 ways to parse XML, either we should use something called XmlDocument or XmlReader so I want to know what is best to use in my case.

Here is exactly what I want to do : I have an XML, I would like to loop through all nodes and search for a specific string inside the node and subnodes and if I found MYSTRING, I note the name of the node with True, and if not, I note the name of the node with False.
I will show you a part of the XML which is too long to make it more clear.
If you look near the end of the XML there is MYSTRING. 
What I want is to loop over all the Jobs in the XML, and check if the job has or not the MYSTRING...Some jobs have it and some others no.
My questions are : what do use ? XML Reader or Document ?
and how to check if inside a node (Job in this example) and the nodes inside it , there is a string called MyString or not.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can Help me.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DSExport>
   <Header CharacterSet="CP1252" ExportingTool="IBM InfoSphere DataStage Export" ToolVersion="8" ServerName="PAR.SL.PRES" ToolInstanceID="dstage1" Date="2017-10-12" Time="15.02.49" ServerVersion="11.5"/>
   <Job Identifier="JxD" TimeModified="11.59.45">
      <Record Identifier="ROOT" Type="JobDF" Readonly="0">
         <Property Name="Name">Suivi</Property>
         <Property Name="Description">Initialisation des datasets</Property>
         <Property Name="NextID">29</Property>
   <Property Name="ControlAfterSubr">0</Property>
         <Collection Name="Parameters" Type="Parameters">
            <SubRecord>
               <Property Name="Name">pathdataset</Property>
               <Property Name="Prompt">pathdataset</Property>
               <Property Name="Default">/home/intdwh/DSdataset</Property>
               <Property Name="ParamType">5</Property>
               <Property Name="ParamLength">0</Property>
               <Property Name="ParamScale">0</Property>
            </SubRecord>
   </Collection>
         <Property Name="Container">V0</Property>
   
         <Property Name="FullDescription" PreFormatted="1">Ce job : 
- cr&#xE9;&#xE9; des datasets vides
- vides les datasets des donn&#xE9;es

Les datasets auquels sont rajout&#xE9;s 1 informations : VERSION


Modification du 05/02/2013 par A.dupont

la variable &quot;LaDate&quot; retourne MYSTRING\(20)</Property>
 </Record>
   </Job>
   </DSExport>
```

Comment: Have you tried or looked up `XDocument`?

Comment: Try [Linq to XML](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples)

Comment: The choice of tool depends on the expected size of your documents. Are those humongous xmls? Then you won't want them to reside in memory completely but rather process line by line. Are they rather small/medium sized? Then you can read them in completely and use XPath expressions for example.

Comment: they are suggesting me to use xdocument, suppose i will use XMLdocument, how can I list all Jobs and say if this job contain or not MyString which is not in the job itself but in some sub nodes as you see in the xml ?

Comment: Look around here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-xml-trees and especially here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-an-element-with-a-specific-child-element

Comment: this doc is using LINQ  not xdocuments. personnaly am looking now at this tutorial but dunno how to find the string itself http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly No one gave me an exact answer of what I wanted here, but I finally got the solution my self;

I used XmlDocument

I used the option SelectNodes to get my nodes, but the most important was to use sometimes the .//MyNode to get relative nodes, based on current one..If we don't use .// we will get all nodes in the documents not the ones relatives to current nodes.
I used something like that to succeed
 XmlNodeList PropertyNodes = itemNode.SelectNodes(".//Property");

Thanks anyway to anyone who tried to help.